# How do I get the lets from the For into a table

Tags: swift

I can not seem to be able to work out how to use a for and add the data from the for into a table
Any help would be appreciated

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    struct Class: Codable {
        let prop_id: String
        let prop_location: String
        let prop_price: String
        enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
            case prop_id = "prop_id"
            case prop_location = "prop_location"
            case prop_price = "prop_price"
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let url = URL(string: "https://pricepointproperty.co.uk/appServices/service.php")

        // Load the URL
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            // If there are any errors don't try to parse it, show the error
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { print(error!); return }

            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let classes = try! decoder.decode([Class].self, from: data)

            // Print out the classes to the console - try sticking this in a table view :)
            for Properties in classes {
                print("\t")
                let id: String = (Properties.prop_id)
                let location: String = (Properties.prop_location)
                let price: String = (Properties.prop_price)
                print(id)
                print(price)
                print(location)
            }
        }).resume()
   }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let myCell = UITableViewCell()
        myCell.textLabel?.text = "location"
        return myCell
    } 
}
```

Comment: You should create a struct for your data and then add instances of that struct to an array and use as data source for your table. There are plenty of tutorials online on how to use a table view.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `Class` definition is fine, the `CodingKeys` enum is not needed but it is okay to leave it like that.

To keep simple you can declare a variable inside `ViewController` of type `[Class]`, this array will hold that data fetched from your url. When you decode this data you save it to that variable, for instance you could do something like: `self?.myData = try! decoder.decode([Class].self, from: data)`.

The myData variable is declare like this:

```
fileprivate var myData = [Class]() {
  didSet {
    // All UI related stuff must run on the main thread
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self?.table.reloadData()
    }
  }
}
```

Using `didSet` property observer is a simple way to reload the data once the variable is updated.

For the table's data source you should implement a couple of methods. First the one that simple returns the number of rows in section with just a line of code:

```
return myData.count
```

And the method that implements `cellForRowAt` which dequeues a cell and set the information on the appropriate cells' fields. The data to be displayed is in `myData` array, you can use the `indexPath` to subscript the array, like this:

```
let dataRow = myData[indexPath.row]
```

You can look at a very simple project that implements all this at [Github](https://github.com/acyrman/StackOverflow58252018). The project's single view looks like this:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: `[weak self]` is not needed. `DispatchQueue` closures don't cause retain cycles.